# Setting up a JAGS model with prior data

Tags: r, jags

I have set up my JAGS function but cannot get the fitted model to work using prior data. I have added all of my steps below if anyone knows what this error means. I think its something to do with how i have tried to pass my new data but unsure, any pointers would be much appreciated

```
#1. set up the JAGs function
jags.mod = function(){
  #Observation model
  for (i in 2:N) {
    Ohio[i] ~ dnorm(Y[i],tau.v)
    }
  Ohio[1] ~ dnorm(Y[1],tau.v)
  tau.v ~ dgamma(1,0.01)
  #System model
 for(i in 2:N){
   Y[i] ~ dnorm(Y[i-1],tau.w)
    }
  Y[1] ~ dnorm(6,0.001)
  tau.w ~ dgamma(1,0.01)
  sigma.w = 1/sqrt(tau.w)
}
```

#2. prepare the data
#define into a list that JAGS requires
jags.data = as.list(Ohio_pm25)

```
#parameters we want to monitor
jags.param = c('Y', 'tau.w', 'sigma.w')

#specify initial values for 2 chains
inits1 = list('Y' = -5, 'tau.w' = 10)
inits2 = list('Y' = 5, 'tau.w' = -10)
jags.inits = list(inits1, inits2)


#3. fitting the JAGS model
jags.mod.fit = jags(data = jags.data, #jags.data is ohio_PM2.5
                inits = jags.inits, 
                parameters.to.save = jags.param, 
                n.chains = 2, 
                n.iter = 100000,
                n.burnin = 5000,
                n.thin = 1, 
                model.file = jags.mod, 
                DIC = FALSE)
```

data snipets;

ohio_data

```
     X Obs        Exp       SMR
1   1  14  15.678357 0.8929507
2   2  56  62.786481 0.8919117
3   3  26  26.953383 0.9646284
4   4  57  59.448398 0.9588147
5   5  21  25.710943 0.8167728
6   6  22  24.764319 0.8883749
7   7  67  52.437394 1.2777141
8   8  18  19.082278 0.9432836
```

ohio_pm2.5

```
Ohio_pm25
      Date     pm2.5
1   1988-01-01  3.100000
2   1988-01-02  3.000000
3   1988-01-03  8.600000
4   1988-01-04  8.866667
5   1988-01-05  2.800000
6   1988-01-06  3.400000
7   1988-01-07  4.600000
8   1988-01-08  3.900000
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your code:

your data needs to be a list and the name of the data must have the same name  as in the jags code ("Ohio"). Moreover, it must have the same dimension as in the jags-Code. As you select Ohio[i], it should be one-dimensional. So, I guess, your data must look like the following:

```
jags.data <- list(Ohio = ohio_pm2.5$pm2.5)
```

I have to admit, that I do not understand how ohio_data fits into your question.